# AE: Limit Characters in random range selector animation

Tags: after-effects, animation, after-effects-expressions

I'm animating a roulette table; above the roulette is an animated text with random numbers untill the winning numbers apears on the roulette table; but the random numbers are from 0-99; i've made it so that the 2 numbers are each on a layer; so that limits it to 0-9; but i would like the animation of the first layer to 0,1,2 or 3. I was searching for a regex but i have no clue what i'm doing...

In any way; i would love it when the random numnbers would be between 00 and 36 as that are the only numbers on a roulette table.

Thanks guys !

Answer (score 0):

To do this on one text layer you could use this expression in the sourceText:

```
Math.round(random(36));
```

If you'd like to keep the two layers then on the first layer use:

```
Math.round(random(3));
```

and on the second layer use:

```
Math.round(random(9));
```

The number in the brackets of the random expression is the limit, so if it's set to 100, the random expression will return a value between 0 and 100.

Comment: Thanks ! But; i'm probably doing something wrong because i'm still saying higher numbers in my random count. 
https://ibb.co/y6s8vyv

Comment: Is it the text animator? If it's changing the character value then this may be the cause - try removing the text animator and see if it limits the randomness.

Comment: If you make an expression like this:

Math.round(random(36));

You will get random numbers between 0 and 35, as the expression counts from zero.

A roulette table has numbers from 0-36, so you probably want

Math.round(random(37));